# Model is set to null when i submit it

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to update records inside a Table, but when i submit the record the model it set to Null.

What i want to happen is to have a multi table single view page where i can edit my ParentModel
and the records inside my model1s

i have a submit button for Parentmodel which works
and a submit button for each recods in Model1s

but everytime i submit any model1s records the debug says that my model is Null

i'm quite new with ASP.Net and already search alot from this forum,
i hope you can help me out

Cheers

View Model

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{

    public class CombineModel
    {
        public ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Model1> Model1s { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Controller

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CombineModelController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            CombineModel CombineModel = new CombineModel();

            CombineModel.ParentModel = db.ParentModel.Find(id);
            CombineModel.Model1s = db.Model1.Where(x => x.ParentId.Equals(id));

            if (CombineModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(CombineModel);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Details(CombineModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(model.ParentModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            CombineModel CombineModel = new CombineModel();

            CombineModel.ParentModel = db.ParentModel.Find(model.ParentModel.ParentId);
            CombineModel.Model1s = db.Model1.Where(x => x.ParentId.Equals(model.ParentModel.ParentId));

            if (CombineModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(CombineModel);
        }




               [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditChild([Bind(Prefix = "Model1")] Model1 model)
        {
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "CombineModel", new { id = model.ParentId });
        }




    }
}
```

View

```html
@model WebApplication1.Models.CombineModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Combine Model</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentModel.ParentId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentModel.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentModel.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>

        </tr>

        
        @foreach (var item in Model.Model1s)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditChild", "CombineModel", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ParentId)
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save-2" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>

            </tr>
        }




    </table>






@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Since your data is posted in the request body, your action method signature should be `public ActionResult Details([FromBody]CombineModel model)`

Comment: the error is happening on the EditChild method, the Details method is working fine and is able to edit the ParentModel record, the Model1s are the one im trying to edit